# Style input placeholder color style with ng-classes

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am having difficulties targeting an input placeholder text when the ng classes are on an input field. I am able to taget the inputs background color but not the placeholder text color. Any assistance would be great.

HTML:

```
<form class="my-form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Quick test" required/>
</form>
```

Scss:

```
.my-form {
 input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
 background: #efefef;
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF0000;
 }
 :-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF0000;
 }
 ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF0000;
 }
 :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF0000;
  }
 }
}
```

Classes Angular adds to a required element

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Quick test" required="" 
class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the ng-class to the vendor prefix does the trick.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Quick test" required="" 
class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched">
```

Scss:

```
.ng-touched::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: red; }
.ng-untouched::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #cccccc; }
/* add additional vendor prefixes or utilize mixin */
```

Answer (score 3):

I added a ng-class conditional on my input placeholder

css:

```
.colorwhiteinput::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color: #ffffff;
}
.colorwhiteinput:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 1;
}
.colorwhiteinput::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 1;
}
.colorwhiteinput:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

html:

```
<input class="flexsearch--input"  ng-class="({put condition here without curve brackets}) ? 'colorwhiteinput' : ''" type="search" placeholder="search" ng-model="searchTerm" name="searchTerm">
```

So just put colorwhiteinput to access the placeholder elements. everything after colorwhiteinput in the css is just targeting so don't change the ::-webkit-input-placeholder etc.